# GPTQQuantizer - custom dataset or load current available dataset locally

Tags: large-language-model, quantization, llama

I am trying to quantize my finetuned model.  I have loaded my model and tokenizer and I need either use my custom dataset or load the current available ones ["wikitext2", "c4", "c4-new", "ptb", "ptb-new"] locally.

Based on the source code quantization_config.py.

User can only use the available datasets:

```
if isinstance(self.dataset, str):
                if self.dataset not in ["wikitext2", "c4", "c4-new", "ptb", "ptb-new"]:
                    raise ValueError(
                        f"""You have entered a string value for dataset. You can only choose between
                        ['wikitext2','c4','c4-new','ptb','ptb-new'], but we found {self.dataset}"""
                    )
            elif not isinstance(self.dataset, list):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"""dataset needs to be either a list of string or a value in
                    ['wikitext2','c4','c4-new','ptb','ptb-new'], but we found {self.dataset}"""
                )
```

dataset needs to be among the list, otherwise, it raise a ValueError.

If you check the definition of variables on top of the code:

```
dataset (`Union[List[str]]`, *optional*):
            The dataset used for quantization. You can provide your own dataset in a list of string or just use the
            original datasets used in GPTQ paper ['wikitext2','c4','c4-new','ptb','ptb-new']
```

It says you can provide your own dataset in a list of string.

Questions:  How should I load a custom dataset and then pass a string to the dataset?  Even if I do that it raises the ValueError.

How can I load a dataset from the list loaclly? I need to be able to provide the path of the dataset.

[https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/utils/quantization_config.py][1]